# Всем элементам после первого положительного отнять 0.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]

b = list(filter(lambda z: z > 0, x))
y = x.index(b[0])
for i in x[y: -1]:
    x[i] -= 0.5
    x[i] += 1
print(x)
```

Результат:

> ```
> [-3, -5, 3.5, 5.0, -3.5, 2.5, -2, -5.5, 5]
> ```

Почему числа как-то странно считает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что у вас в `i` попадают значение не от `y` и до `len(x)`, а все значения списка, т.е. вначале 4, потом -4 и т.д. лучше использовать `range`

также не понятна зачем нужна строка `x[i] += 1`, её можно убрать

необязательно получать все значения из `filter`, лучше получить первое с помощью функции `next`

```
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]

b = next(filter(lambda z: z > 0, x))
y = x.index(b)
for i in range(y + 1, len(x)):
    x[i] -= 0.5

print(x)
```

Comment: `Всем элементам после первого положительного отнять 0.5`, так что `range(y + 1, len(x)`

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]

enabled = False

for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] -= 0.5 * enabled
    enabled = enabled or x[i] > 0

print(x)
```

алгоритм:

1. проходим по всем элементам массива
2. у каждого элемента вычитаем `0.5 * enabled`, если `enabled = False`, то соответственно ничего вычитаться не будет (`0.5 * 0`) иначе будет вычтено `0.5` (`0.5 * 1`)
3. если `x[i] > 0`, то устанавливаем `enabled` в `True`, но чтобы сделать это в одну строку требуется выполнить более сложную проверку:

если `enabled == True` ничего не меняем при любом значении элемента иначе если `x[i] > 0` устанавливаем в True

такую проверку можно записать как

```
enabled = enabled or x[i] > 0
```

т.е. если `enabled` `True`, то его значение не изменится иначе будет установлено по условию

4. вычисление  `enabled` после вычисления `x[i]` позволяет менять элементы ПОСЛЕ первого положительного, а не НАЧИНАЯ С первого положительного

Comment: хорошо, выполнено